# What's the fastest way to make concurrent web requests in Perl?

Tags: perl, concurrency

I need to make some concurrent XML feed requests in Perl. What is the *fastest* way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean fastest as in: a solution that will be fastest to implement, or a solution that will be fastest once implemented?

Answer (score 10):

I would probably use [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent/), perhaps like this:

```
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;


sub get_feeds {
    my @feeds = @_;
    my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;
    my %results;
    $done->begin( sub { $done->send(\%results) } );

    for my $feed (@feeds){
        $done->begin;
        http_get $feed, sub { $results{$feed} = \@_; $done->end };
    }

    $done->end;
    return $done;
}

my $done = get_feeds(...);
my $result = $done->recv; # block until all feeds are fetched
```

Comment: The link to AnyEvent::HTTP is http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-HTTP/.

Answer (score 4):

[HTTP::Async](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Async/) is pretty fast and quite easy to code.

Comment: Crucially, it returns HTTP::Response objects, so you can slot it in almost painlessly in place of LWP.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, [AnyEvent::Curl::Multi](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3A%3ACurl%3A%3AMulti) is a non-blocking library built on top of libcurl.  Very fast and tons of concurrency available.  Much more powerful than AnyEvent::HTTP, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I used [LWP::Parallel::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~marclang/ParallelUserAgent/) for something similar.  An example from the POD:

```
require LWP::Parallel::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::Parallel::UserAgent->new();
...

$ua->redirect (0); # prevents automatic following of redirects
$ua->max_hosts(5); # sets maximum number of locations accessed in parallel
$ua->max_req  (5); # sets maximum number of parallel requests per host
...
$ua->register ($request); # or
$ua->register ($request, '/tmp/sss'); # or
$ua->register ($request, \&callback, 4096);
...
$ua->wait ( $timeout ); 
...
sub callback { my($data, $response, $protocol) = @_; .... }
```

Comment: LWP::Parallel fails its tests at the moment, though.

Comment: I think it is no longer maintained. I moved all of my work to use AnyEvent::HTTP.